# Prevent text from being overwritten by stream.write() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, terminal, node.js, chat

I am using Node.js to create a chat. Essentially, it uses the net module to create a server. Everyone that connects to the server is added to a list. Inputting data to the server forEach()s through the list of participants, and streams them the message via .write(). There's a problem, though. If you are typing (and you type directly into the terminal window) and something is written to your stream, everything you have typed (but not yet submitted) is overwritten. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I doubt it. You probably shouldn't even be using something so rudimentary for a chat program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using low level `stdin` / `stdout` then there is in fact nothing you can do (unless you clear the screen and redraw your own buffer each time).

Normally if you want to stay in the terminal, you'd use curses. A quick gaze at the [modules page](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Modules) reveals that there is a [ncurses binding](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses) for Node.js.

I haven't tested that, but that seems to be the fastest way of getting the thing done (that is, in case it still works in 2.5/3.x) if you want to stay old school terminal.